# Подключить второй модуль, использующий код из первого

Tags: android

Мне надо создать отдельное приложение на основе первого, которое будет реализовывать немного другой функционал.

Я прочитал, что для этого можно создать отдельный модуль на основе предыдущего.
Но проблема в том, что первый модуль компилируется как apk, что не дает использовать его как зависимость.

Потом создал отдельный модуль library куда в build gradle перенес общие зависимости и подключил этот модуль к 2 другим. Android Studio классы находит, но почему то код не исполняется.

[image: Вот примерная структура:]

build.gradle из mylibrary:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

build.gradle основного модуля
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите, что ли, структуру проекта и как вы модули в градле подключили. И как вызываете в приложении код из библиотеки

Comment: Gradle файлы лучше текстом, не картинкой. И вы не показали где и как вы вызываете код, который не исполняется